# How to pass variable to windows.h function text()?

Tags: c++

First off, I googled the hell out of this then searched the forums.  In my ignorance of how the TEXT() function operates I cannot find an efficient way to search for an answer.

I writing a piece of code to search for a file that relies on inputting the directory you want to search.  However, when I pass anything but a literal value to the function, like displayContent(_TEXT("c:\")), the software does not execute properly.  It does not search for anything.  Inserting breakpoints doesn't tell much, as the software closes anyways.

I would like to pass a variable to the the displayContent function by placing TEXT(variable) inside its argument like displayContent(_TEXT(*ptrDir)) but that is not compiling.  Furthermore, when I simply place ptrDir inside of the argument of displayContent the software compiles but does not execute properly, as it asks for the directory to search but does not actually search it.

What's happening here?  There has to be a way to pass a variable to displayContent that includes a string that's recieved from the user.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h> 
#include <tchar.h>    
#include "Strsafe.h"  
#include <string>

using namespace std;

typedef wchar_t WCHAR;  

#define CONST const 
typedef CONST WCHAR* LPCWSTR;

int displayContent(LPCWSTR lpszPath, int level = 0) {     
    wcout << lpszPath << endl;
    getchar();
    getchar();

    WIN32_FIND_DATA  ptrFileData;

    HANDLE hFile = NULL;
    BOOL bGetNext = TRUE;
    wchar_t lpszNewPath[MAX_PATH];

    if (lstrlen(lpszPath) > MAX_PATH)
        return -1;

    StringCchCopy(lpszNewPath, MAX_PATH, lpszPath);

    StringCchCat(lpszNewPath, MAX_PATH, _TEXT("*.*"));

    hFile = FindFirstFile(lpszNewPath, &ptrFileData);

    while (bGetNext)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < level; i++)
            wcout << "-";

        if (ptrFileData.dwFileAttributes == FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY
            && lstrlen(ptrFileData.cFileName) > 2)
        {

            wchar_t lpszFirstTimePath[MAX_PATH];

            StringCchCopy(lpszFirstTimePath, MAX_PATH, lpszPath);

            StringCchCat(lpszFirstTimePath, MAX_PATH, ptrFileData.cFileName);

            StringCchCat(lpszFirstTimePath, MAX_PATH, _TEXT("\\"));

            wcout << ">" << ptrFileData.cFileName << endl;

            displayContent(lpszFirstTimePath, level + 2);
        }
        else
        {

            wcout << ">" << ptrFileData.cFileName << endl;
        }

        bGetNext = FindNextFile(hFile, &ptrFileData);
    }

    FindClose(hFile);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    WCHAR directory;
    LPCWSTR ptrDir;
    ptrDir = &directory;


    cout << "Enter directory you wish to search: " << endl;
    //cin >> directory;
    directory = 'c:\\' ;
    ptrDir = &directory;


    displayContent(_TEXT(*ptrDir));
    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `_TEXT` is not a function, it is a preprocessor macro. It's designed to work only with string literals and it cannot accept variables.

Comment: Where is a good resource to learn more about this?  Search engines and my reference books have been useless for this.

Comment: Related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16061264/strings-tchar-lpwcs-lpctstr-cstring-whats-what-here-simple-quick/16067164#16067164

Comment: You need double quotes and the `_TEXT` macro in the line where you initialize `directory`:  `directory = _TEXT("c:\\");`  When you use single quotes, you're telling the compiler that you want a single character rather than a string.  Make sure you enable compiler warnings.

Comment: Also, if you want to use wide strings in i/o, you can use std::wcout and std::wcin in place of std::cout and std::cin, which, in this problem, should eliminate the need for conversions.

Comment: Adrian that makes sense. I had tried that before, but now I see that since I declared 'directory' as a 'char' that it will not work until I change that as well.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `_TEXT` (and equivalently, `_T`) macro is strictly for literals (string literals or character literals). It expands to `L` for a Unicode build, and to nothing for a narrow-character build. So, for a string like (say) `"hello"`, you'll get `L"hello"` for a Unicode build and `"hello"` for a narrow-character build. This gives you a wide literal in a Unicode build and a narrow literal otherwise.

If you have a string in a variable, you can convert between wide and narrow characters with the [MultiByteToWideChar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072.aspx) and [WideCharToMultibyte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130.aspx) functions.

In this case, doing a conversion on the contents of a variable isn't really needed though. After eliminating some unnecessary complexity, and using a few standard library types where they make sense, I end up with code something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tchar.h>    
#include <string>

#define UNICODE
#include <windows.h> 

int displayContent(std::wstring const &path, int level = 0) {     
    WIN32_FIND_DATA  FileData;

    if (path.length() > MAX_PATH)
        return -1;

    std::wstring new_path = path + L"\\*.*";

    HANDLE hFile = FindFirstFile(new_path.c_str(), &FileData);

    do {
        if ((FileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) && (FileData.cFileName[0] == L'.'))
            continue;

        std::wcout << std::wstring(level, L'-') << L">" << FileData.cFileName << L"\n";

        if (FileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
            displayContent(path + L"\\" + FileData.cFileName, level + 2);

    } while (FindNextFile(hFile, &FileData));

    FindClose(hFile);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    wchar_t current_dir[MAX_PATH];

    GetCurrentDirectory(sizeof(current_dir), current_dir);

    displayContent(current_dir);
    return 0;
}
```

[Note: I've also changed it to start from the current directory instead of always starting at the root of the C drive, but if you want to change it back, that's pretty trivial--in fact, it simplifies the code a bit more).